# change src attribute of an image - fakepath error

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I want to change `src` attribute of `imgt` and choose only images 960 x 540 and higher.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$('#inpfile').change(function(){
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width;
            var h = this.height;
            if (w < 960 || h < 540){
                alert('image is too small');
            }
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert('wrong file');
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
$('#imgt').attr("src", $(this).val()
$(this).val('');
});
```

I'm getting error: - `file:///C:/fakepath/wplus.jpg`

Any help?